# $AdditiveRank=1$ structure?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Define a matrix $Z\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ to be of $AdditiveRank=1$ structure if there are two vectors $u,v\in\mathbb R^{n}$ with $Z_{ij}=u_i+v_j$ where $n=2^m$.

Is $Z$ is $AdditiveRank=1$ $\iff$ every $2\times2$ submatrix of $Z$ is $AdditiveRank=1$ true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your definition, $Z$ has additive rank $1$ if and only if every two rows of the matrix $\exp(Z):=\|\exp(Z_{ij})\|_{1\le i,j\le n}$ are proportional, and so are every two columns of the matrix; equivalently, if and only if $\exp(Z)$ is rank $1$. Your question thus becomes: is it true that a matrix has rank $1$ if and only if all of its order-$2$ submatrices have rank $1$? The answer, of course, is **YES**.

Comment: How about if all submatrices are consecutive? That is row indices $i,i+1$ and column indices $j,j+1$ (perhaps for last row and column we can wrap around).

Comment: The answer is still the same. My original solution, in fact, uses only this weaker assumption.